# How to avoid storing the username and password as part of the connection string

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

#### Situation

My team works with a NFS. I've written a python script that connects to a database. People execute my python script and based some values associated with their userid in our backend mongodb database the script performs certain actions for them

#### My question

I have a mongodb connection string like so

`database_client = MongoClient("mongodb://<myusername>:<mypassword>@serverip:port/DBName")`

The problem is that anyone can simply read the py script and figure out what my username and password are.

#### What is not an option

Making the Python script and opaque executable is not allowed. Not to mention it doesn't protect my credentials from leaking to other members of the tram who work on the same codebase. Nor is making the db world editable/readable. All requests to edit the db must go through an authorized account and only through the API provided by the script.

Is there a way to do this/what should I be doing instead?

*Edit*: I am **NOT** using Heroku. I'm behind a company firewall and the mongoDB server is a machine with an IP on the company network

Comment: Typically people use environment variables, or something like AWS Parameter Store to avoid keeping secrets in code. Have you looked into either of those options?

Comment: but couldn't users of the script just list their env to find out what the username and password are?

Comment: why not create accounts for everyone in the database?  either that, or create a network service that people can access (e.g web/rest endpoint) instead

Comment: If your scripts have api, then pass your credentials as arguments to your script and parse them using optparse or argparse.

Comment: @SamMason A rest endpoint is a great idea! that way the database interactions are esentially a blackbox!

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to read the username and password from a configuration file<sup>1</sup> such as

```
[topsecret]
user = foo
password = bar
```

This way you can share the code with anyone and they will be able to execute it only if they have the valid configuration file.

<sup>1</sup> You can use the configparser module https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/configparser.html to parse configuration files such as above.